# How to get past the exception - "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Versioned"

Tags: java, rest, jackson, jax-rs

I am new to Java and REST programming. I made one example but am stuck at this exception stated in title above. Any help/clue much appreciated.
I have the jackson annotation and other relevant jars but I think am still missing some more jars - not sure which ones though. The list of jars in my project is now big, hence not adding the list here.

Am using Apache Tomcat v8.0 server with eclipse(Luna 4.4.1 version).

Below is how my code looks like:
1) Object / POJO class

```
package com;
public class Employee {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String country;
    private String salary;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    public String getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(String salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

}
```

2) Service class

```
package com;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/json/emp1")
public class JSONService {

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Employee getEmployeeInJSON() {

        Employee emp1 = new Employee();
        emp1.setId(999);
        emp1.setName("JasonEmployee");
        emp1.setCountry("JasonCountry");
        emp1.setSalary("JasonSalary");

        return emp1;

    }

    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response createEmployeeInJSON(Employee emp1) {

        String result = "Employee created : " + emp1;
        return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();

    }

}
```

3) Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<display-name>Rest1</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>
                    com, com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json
         </param-value>
     </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

Comment: You probably are missing JAR files. Specifically, Jackson Core. I'd recommend converting your project into a Maven/Gradle project so you don't have to mess with JAR files yourself, though

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
I have below:
        jackson-annotations-2.1.2.jar
 jackson-core-2.0.5-sources.jar
 jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar
 jackson-jaxrs-base-2.2.3.jar
 jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.2.3.jar
 jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.1.2.jar

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 2.x Jackson jar file. As suggested by cricket_007; you can convert to Maven to be hassle free. 
http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload

Comment: I have below:

        jackson-annotations-2.1.2.jar
 jackson-core-2.0.5-sources.jar
 jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar
 jackson-jaxrs-base-2.2.3.jar
 jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.2.3.jar
 jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.1.2.jar

I was just hoping I would not have to switch to Maven. However if this problem persists, then I might as well. Wanted to give a shot before moving on.

Comment: Are you sure your jar files are present on the class path while you are executing the program. your error states that com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Versioned class is not found which is present in jackson-core-2.0.5-sources.jar, so definitely this jar is missing from class path.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is that the different jackson jars are of different versions. Try to make the jars *jackson-annotations, jackson-core, jackson-databind* of same version.